# scrape data from json file

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape `name` from json file but they show me error that `string indices must be integers` as you see below json code
Json file:

```
 "prodBean": {
            "subProdTerms": null,
            "friendlyUrl": "/brakes-wheel-end/brake-drums-rotors/brake-drum/otr-brake-drum-otr1601b",
            "name": "OTR 16.5 x 7 Brake Drum, Balanced",
            "showSubscriptionSelection": false,
            "UnitOfMeasure": "EA",
            "qtyPerUnit": 1.0,
            "sequence": 2,
            "availMsg": null,
            "ProductStatus": "Released",
            "ProductType": "Product",
            "sku": "OTR-OTR1601B",
            "id": "a8G1W000000Y7DfUAK",
            "showNewSubscriptionSelection": false,
            "savings": 405.49,
            "basePrice": 405.492,
            "price": 0.0,
            "ECrossReferencesS"
```

Code

```
import json

with open("test.json","r") as file:
    temp=json.load(file)

for item in temp:
    title=item['prodBean']['name']
    print(title)
```

Answer (score 0):

The load statement in your case returns a `dict`. When you iterate a dict with a single parameter, you get just the keys:

```
>>> for item in temp:
...     print(item)
...
prodBean
```

You need to iterate the dict with `.items()`, then you'll have access to the data:

```
>>> for k, v in temp.items():
...     item = v['name']
...     print(item)
...
OTR 16.5 x 7 Brake Drum, Balanced
```